# JMeter JSR223 PreProcessor - My random and current date turns itself into something in the year of 1970

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am trying to create random date within two limit date with JSR223. And here is my code:

```
"import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;



SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");



String formattedDate = df.format(${__RandomDate(,2021-10-20,2021-11-20,,)});
vars.put("myFutureDate",formattedDate);"
```

But when i format the date and put into a variable called myFutureDate, the date becomes 01/01/1970. Could you please help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts because:

1. They conflict with [Groovy GStrings](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_gstring_and_string_hashcodes)
2. They might resolve into something causing compilation failure or runtime unexpected behaviour
3. They're compiled and cached so only first occurrence will be used, your `${myFutureDate}` variable will be the same for all iterations

So

1. Put your __RandomDate() function to the "Parameters" section of your JSR223 Test Element
2. Use the following code to re-format the random date:

   ```
   vars.put('myFutureDate', Date.parse('yyyy-mm-dd', Parameters).format('dd/MM/yyyy'))
   ```

[image]

More information:

- [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri, you just saved me!